# Create an object from ActiveRecord format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In trying to debug an issue that's appearing in production, I would like to copy some of the live data into my local database.

To begin with, I'm just trying to copy the latest two records.

```
payments = Payment.all[-2..-1]
```

Here is the return.  I've censored most of the info for client and customer privacy.

```
[#<Payment id: 1400, payment_number: "###", user_id: ###, project_id: 85, phase_id: 155, amount: "500", notes: nil, status: "complete", created_at: "2023-03-16 16:50:23.434401000 -0400", updated_at: "2023-03-16 16:50:23.447559000 -0400", description: "###", processed_at: nil, payout_category: "manual">, #<Payment id: 1402, payment_number: "###", user_id: ###, project_id: nil, phase_id: nil, amount: nil, notes: "###", status: "incomplete", created_at: "2023-03-17 03:02:56.445550000 -0400", updated_at: "2023-03-20 11:42:56.153214000 -0400", description: "###", processed_at: nil, payout_category: "hyperwallet">]
```

In the past, I've successfully copied records by manually pasting the data into a notepad.  Then I replace the pointy braces "<>" with curly brackets "{}", and delete the id attribute.  This creates a hash that I can iterate across to populate a new record.

It seems like Rails would have a better way to read such a record in this format, since that's the way it spits them out.  Is there a less time-consuming and error-prone way to create records in the console when given input in ActiveRecord format?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Can you connect to both DBs from the console? `Payment.last.dup' will create the payment record with an :id of nil. You could loop through the records you want to copy, create a duplicate, then save that duplicate to the other DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.dup` to make copies of the records with nil ids, then `.upsert_all` to insert them. If you have both DB connections setup in your database.yml then you can use that reference for the connections.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:productions)

dupes = Payment.all[-2..-1].map {|p| p.dup}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)

Payment.upsert_all(dupes)
```

Comment: This looks very promising if I can figure out how to connect to the production database from my development console.  It shouldn't be too hard, since it's on Heroku.  But do you happen to know of a resource that could help me figure it out quicker?

Comment: I would just download a copy of production and load it into your local DB server. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export Then I would create an entry in database.yml that points to it. You could call it something like :prod_local.